# Finding metric to make a submanifold minimal

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I would like to ask a question, which I am not sure if there exist some known results (that I could not locate).

Given a smooth embedded submanifold $M$ in $\mathbb R^n,$ is it always possible to find a Riemannian metric $g$ on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $M,$ as a Riemannian submanifold of $(\mathbb R^n,g),$ is minimal?

More generally, one may replace $\mathbb R^n$ with an arbitrary smooth manifold, but I am not even sure if this problem is open in the euclidean case.

Any comments or ideas are welcome!

Comment: Embedded submanifold or immersed?

Comment: I do not know anything for either. Let's say embedded.

Comment: If $M$ has a well-defined tubular neighbourhood, then it seems to me you could construct such a $g$ as a product metric, setting up so that the parallel translates of $M$ are isometric. Globally you should be able to define this by combining it with the Euclidean metric via a cutoff function. Note that $M$ would have to be at least properly embedded for this to make sense.

Comment: This sounds reasonable! I would try to see if I could make it up. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: OK, let me know if you get stuck - you could post the details as an answer when you're done. Note that this ought to work in any ambient manifold, but it also points to some obstructions when $M$ is only immersed. If for example $M$ is the union of a plane and a sphere in $\mathbf{R}^3$, then you would have to change the metric in ways that seem incompatible.

Comment: @LeoMoos:  I don't understand what you mean by 'constructing such a $g$ as a product metric, setting up so that the parallel translates of $M$ are isometric.'  You would have to assume that the normal bundle of $M$ in Euclidean $n$-space is trivial in order to be able to do this, and the normal bundle of $M$ is not generally trivial.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Mmh, you're right, I was a bit careless there, thanks for pointing this out. I guess I was mentally checking my argument against the codimension one case, where the triviality of the bundle holds provided the ambient space is simply connected, per an argument of [Samelson](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-01/S0002-9939-1969-0245026-9/S0002-9939-1969-0245026-9.pdf) for example. Do you have an argument in mind for the non-trivial case?

Comment: @LeoMoos:  That said, one can always find a metric on a vector bundle so that the zero section is a minimal submanifold of the vector bundle (the metric can't be an actual product metric unless the vector bundle is trivial).  Using this idea, one can 'graft' such a metric onto a tubular neighborhood of the embedded $M$ and use a partition of unity to extend it to some metric on the ambient manifold.  If $M$ is compact, then one can do this so that the ambient metric $g$ in which $M$ is minimal is complete.

Comment: @RobertBryant: OK, I understand - thank you for fixing the argument.